# XCode clang error no such file or directory with Push Plugin (Cordova project)

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-pushplugin

I am developing a cordova project. A project which is intended to run cross platform: Android, Windows phone, iOS.

I using this pushplugin to implement push notifications: the push plugin is intended to communicate between the device and the relevant push notification system (Android: GCM, Windows: WNS, Apple: APNS): https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push

On a windows pc, in the visual studio, I have managed to implement push notifications in a todo app. The app runs well in the cross platform solution which runs on visual studio.

Now as you may know, in a Cordova app, when building for a specific platform, folders for each platform are created as sub folders to a folder called platforms found in the project directory.

When I tried building for ios and put the project folder on a ios computer, I am opening the project in Xcode and trying to run it, but I am getting these kind of errors referring to the same push plugin:

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/Jurgen/Documents/Xcode/backbonetodo/BackboneToDo/platforms/ios/BackboneToDoPluginsphonegap-plugin-pushGCMLibrarieslibGGLCloudMessaging.a'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/Jurgen/Documents/Xcode/backbonetodo/BackboneToDo/platforms/ios/BackboneToDoPluginsphonegap-plugin-pushGCMLibrarieslibGGLCore.a'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/Jurgen/Documents/Xcode/backbonetodo/BackboneToDo/platforms/ios/BackboneToDoPluginsphonegap-plugin-pushGCMLibrarieslibGGLInstanceIDLib.a'
```

I just copied the first 3 errors (but there are over 20).

The push plugin works fine on visual studio and normally by copying the project folder on a mac computer and running the .xcodeproject file from inside the iOS platform folder, I manage to run with no problems.

Any idea, what could be wrong? I am also notificing that after BackboneToDo there is no / and also after Plugins. It seems like the way it is creating the directory is not right. I also tried to change the location to absolute but this didnt solve the problem.

Any help?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

While coping the files of deferent platforms make sure you don't copy the following files / folders.

cordova_plugins.js, cordova-js-src, cordova.js, plugins.

It seems like you have copied the push plugin for android in iOS project.

Comment: Do you mean in the IOS folder there shouldnt be the mentioned files/folders ? I should have no plugins folder in the ios folder?